# Url Mod-Rewrite Get new Page with ID

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i need some help from the experts.

I have some rewrite rules:

```
post.php go to http://example.com/post/3/
RewriteRule ^post/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

It Works!

But, How can i add a new rewrite rule to the NEW Page Users.php after post/ID/
And get the ID in Users.php (Users.php?id=3)

Like this http://example.com/post/3/users

Thanks!

Comment: So `/post/3/` must go to `/post.php?id=3`. That works. But also `/post/3/users/' should go to `/Users.php?id=3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `/post/3/users/` to go to `/Users.php?id=3`, you have to put that rule before your existing rule. Your existing rule matches `/post/3/'` which is a prefix of what this additional rule matches, so that rule will never fire if it is after.

```
# catch the longer URL first
RewriteRule ^post/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/users/?$ Users.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

# No /users/ on it; rewrite to post.php
RewriteRule ^post/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Another thing: you tagged your post with `.htaccess`. Does that mean your rewrites are in a `.htaccess`? If so, you should use `RewriteBase` because your rewrites are relative. Why it's working is probably that you are allowing a 1:1 correspondence between paths and URLs on your webserver.

In a per-directory context like `.htaccess`, mod_rewrite is working with path names, not URLs.  But if you do a relative rewrite, the path is turned into a URL and fed back into the Apache's request handling chain to be processed over again. How the path is turned into a URL is that the contents of `RewriteBase` are added to the front. If you don't have `RewriteBase` then a silly thing happens: the path to your directory (that was removed for the `RewriteRule` is just tacked back on!).

Example: suppose your DocumentRoot is `/var/www`.  Suppose the browser asks for the URL `/foo`. This gets translated to the path `/var/www/foo` If inside the `.htaccess` for `/var/www/` you rewrite `foo` to `bar` (and `RewriteBase` is not set), then mod_rewrite will generate the URL `/var/www/bar`: it just takes the `/var/www/` directory that was stripped off and puts it back on. Now that can be made to work: just make `/var/www/` a valid URL going to that directory. For instance with

```
Alias /var/www /var/www # map /var/www URL to /var/www directory
```

But that is hacky. The right way is to have `RewriteBase /` in the .htaccess. So when `foo` is rewritten to `bar`, it just gets a `/` in front and becomes the url `/bar`.  This is fed back to the server and will resolve back to the document root again "naturally".

I used hacks like that before I understood the rewriting. I even used `/` as a `DocumentRoot`! That made everything work out since then most URLs are paths: you don't have to think of URLs a an abstraction separate from your filesystem paths. But it's a dangerous, silly thing.