# How to change url variable with custom variable

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to: URL re-writing in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039725/how-to-url-re-writing-in-php)

My intention is to change the variable (id) passed on the URL with another variable (custom text). 
To more clear I would like to change:

from

```
www.mysite.com/page.php?id=14
```

to

```
www.mysite.com/page.php?id=the_best_product_for_them
```

or even better

```
www.mysite.com/product/the_best_product_for_them
```

There is already a table on my database that associates the id='14' with the text 'the_best_product_for_them' (id, product_name)

I guess this is what wordpress does with permalinks. I know also how to do it manually with a .htaccess file, but I would like to do it dynamically. What I need is a direction where to start from and what is needed to achieve this.

The server is Apache, the code is in PHP.

Many thanks,
Giulio

Comment: This question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php

Comment: Google about VANITY URL's

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'll find solution in here: [Url Mod-Rewrite Get new Page with ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659370/url-mod-rewrite-get-new-page-with-id)

```
# catch URL and  rewrite to index.php
RewriteRule ^product/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

- be sure that you have mod_rewrite at your Apache Server

Comment: I think you missed the point. OP knows how to do it "manually with a .htaccess". He would like to do it dynamically.

Comment: Hi Tom, that's correct. So far the answers given were not really helpful. Except the comment from "trollster", the input was a good start: VANITY URLs --- thank you all!